# How to set image from text file in android

Tags: android, file, imageview

I want to set image to ImageView in following way

1) when click on button image gallery open

2) select any image and set to image view & store that image path to text file

i did all this work but when application close, ones start again, the ImageView does not shows the previous image via retrieve image path from text file

code is below
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }

    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) { 
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData(); 
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri); 
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath); 
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); 
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/ImageLocation.txt"); 
            try { 
                myFile.createNewFile(); 
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile); 
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
                myOutWriter.append(selectedImagePath); 
                myOutWriter.close(); 
                fOut.close(); 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing SD ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) { 
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }; 
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null); 
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 

    return cursor.getString(column_index); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you reading the ImagePath on restart? Please show the code for the same. Also, while writing the ImagePath to the text file you should do the following

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageLocation.txt"); 
    try { 
        if(!myFile.exists()) {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile); 
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
        myOutWriter.append(selectedImagePath); 
        myOutWriter.close(); 
        fOut.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While reading the file also you should read using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

**EDIT:**

If your intention is to just look into the Image Gallery then you should not use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`, change it to `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);`.

Now, the below will be your file path reading function (your file writing code will always overwrite the existing stored path..so you will always have only one path stored....if you desire to store more than one image path then you should modify both your file writing and the below file reading part).

```
public String getStoredPath() {
    String path = null;
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageLocation.txt"); 
    if(myFile.exists()) {
        //Read text from file
        try { 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile)); 
            String line; 
            // Below while loop will only run once as your file writing 
            // always overwrites the existing line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                path = line;
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 

        } 
    }

    return path;
}
```

Then at the place where you want to set the image uri.

```
String imagePath = getStoredPath();
if(imagePath != null) {
    img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath));
}
```

Be sure to make the suggested change for file write. Also, if it is only one image path you want to store and fetch, then consider using Shared Preferences.

Comment: where is the code? Are you talking about `public String getPath(Uri uri)`?

Comment: File file = new File("/sdcard/ImageLocation.txt");

  if(file.exists())   
  {
   //Read text from file

   StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

   try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     text.append(line);
    }
   }
   catch (IOException e) {

   }

   
   ///  img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);    

  // i want to assign image here
   
  }
  else
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry file doesn't exist!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }

Comment: As I had conveyed in my answer, you need to use
`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImageLocation.txt");` while reading or writing to a file. you are still using `/sdcard`. Please change the same

Comment: Also, if there will be only one entry in the text file then consider using SharedPreferences. And if there can be many entries in the text file then you need to take care of reading the different entries

Comment: if i want to read image path which i already store in ImageLocation.txt file and retrive path that path and set image to image view how it possible i wrote img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); but no use

Comment: Please check my final edit. It should work for you. If it helps you then please consider accepting it as answer.